# How do I represent percent of a variable in a filled barplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have a data frame(t1) and I want to illustrate the shares of companies in relation to their size
I added a Dummy variable in order to make a filled barplot and not 3:

```
t1$row <- 1
```

## The size of companies are separated in medium, small and micro:

```
f_size <- factor(t1$size,
               ordered = TRUE,
               levels = c("medium", "small", "micro"))
```

## The plot is build up with the economic_theme:

```
ggplot(t1, aes(x = "Size", y = prop.table(row), fill = f_size)) +
geom_col() +
geom_text(aes(label = as.numeric(f_size)),
position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
theme_economist(base_size = 14) +
scale_fill_economist() +
theme(legend.position = "right", 
    legend.title = element_blank()) +
theme(axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(r = 20))) +
ylab("Percentage") +
xlab(NULL)
```

[image]

How can I modify my code to get the share for medium, small and micro in the middle of the three filled parts in the barplot?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't quite clear to me and I suggest you re-phrase it for clarity. But I believe you're trying to get the annotations to be accurately aligned on the Y-axis. For this use, pre-calculate the labels and then use `annotate`

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(3432)
df <- data.table(
  cat= sample(LETTERS[1:3], 1000, replace = TRUE)
  , x= rpois(1000, lambda = 5)
)

tmp <- df[, .(pct= sum(x) / sum(df[,x])), cat][, cumsum := cumsum(pct)]
ggplot(tmp, aes(x= 'size', y= pct, fill= cat)) + geom_bar(stat='identity') +
  annotate('text', y= tmp[,cumsum] - 0.15, x= 1, label= as.character(tmp[,pct]))
```

[image]

But this is a poor decision graphically. Stacked bar charts, by definition sum to 100%. Rather than labeling the components with text, just let the graphic do this for you via the axis labels:

```
ggplot(tmp, aes(x= cat, y= pct, fill= cat)) + geom_bar(stat='identity') + coord_flip() +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks= seq(0,1,.05))
```

[image]